# O que significa | no Zig?

Tags: zig

Estava testando algumas linguagens, em especial o [Zig](https://ziglang.org/), e me deparei com a necessidade de usar `memset`. Porém na documentação menciona:

> @memset(dest: [*]u8, c: u8, byte_count: usize)

> This function sets a region of memory to c. dest is a pointer.
> This function is a low level intrinsic with no safety mechanisms. Most code should not use this function, instead using something like this:
>
> ```
> for (dest[0..byte_count]) |*b| b.* = c;
> ```

---

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
const bb: []u8 = std.heap.page_allocator.alloc(u8, i) catch return false;
for (bb[0..i]) |*b| {
    b.* = 0;
}
```

Mas, não entendi o que o `|*b|` significa. Na documentação, o `*b` menciona que é um pointeiro, o `b.*` define o valor do pointeiro.

Eu também troquei o código para utilizar:

```
const bb: []u8 = std.heap.page_allocator.alloc(u8, i) catch return false;
var ii: usize = 0;
while (ii < i) : (ii += 1) {
    b[ii] = 0;
}
```

Ele funciona de forma igual, a aparentemente também com a mesma peformance.

---

O uso do `|` também parece em outros pontos da documentação:

```
const allocator = std.heap.direct_allocator;
var download_frame = async fetchUrl(allocator, "https://example.com/");
var awaited_download_frame = false;
errdefer if (!awaited_download_frame) {
    if (await download_frame) |r| allocator.free(r) else |_| {}
};
```

Um outro uso, mas comum:

```
const number = parseU64(str, 10) catch |err| return err;
```

---

O que significa esses `|` e quando utiliza?

Comment: https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.9.0/#Optionals (mais detalhes no if with optional, while with optional, etc). Não vou elaborar resposta, mas só pra adiantar e simplficando em excesso é "se houver valor, refira a ele por esse |nome| e passe pro que vier em seguida." - é um dos jeitos do zig teoricamente contornar problemas de null (teoricamente. na prática não vejo null como o problema que dizem que é e nem isso como solução, é só outro jeito de lidar mesmo).